# Prove that $\|∇f(x) − ∇f(y)\| ≤ M\|x − y\|.$

Tags: convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

In the context of convex optimisation, suppose $f$ is a convex function, differentiable with $∇f$, and suppose $0 ⪯ ∇^{2}f ⪯ MI$.

I want to show that $\|∇f(x) − ∇f(y)\| ≤ M\|x − y\|$. I am not sure how to do that.

And one more follow-up to this proof. If we use norm $\|·\|_∞$, do we have another constant $M'$ such that $\|∇f(x) − ∇f(y)\|_∞ ≤ M'\|x − y\|_∞$?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You certainly need some knowledge on $f$ and or $\nabla f$, furthermore I would assume that this inequality holds only on a restricted domain $\Omega$.

Comment: @DanDoe I have edited the question sorry for leaving out the context

Comment: You seem to be confused in this question.  You're being asked to show that $\nabla f$ has Lipschitz constant $M$, but you're also assuming that it has Lipschitz constant $M$.  It would help if you clarified the statement of the problem.

Comment: @BrianBorchers it was wrong to assume it has Lipschitz constant M, I have corrected it

Comment: Try using Taylor's theorem with an appropriate remainder term.

Comment: Is $f$ defined on a bounded domain? If not, $\nabla f$ may not be Lipschitz. Consider $x,y\in \mathbb R$ and  $f(x)=e^x$. Then $f$ is smooth and convex, but there cannot exist $M$ such that $|f’(x)-f’(y)|\leq M|x-y|$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb R$ (unless $x,y$ are in a bounded domain).

Comment: @MengchunZhang But your $f$ does not satisfy $f''\le M.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Oh yes, now I see the update, thanks!

Comment: @needhelppls Simply apply to $g:=\nabla f$ the usual theorem: if $\forall x\in\Omega$ (convex), $\|\nabla g(x)\|\le M,$ then $g$ is $M$-Lipschitz on $\Omega.$

Answer (score 1):

Given $y$ and $x$, define the function $g:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,  $$g(t) = (\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y))^{T}(\nabla f(y+t(x-y)) - \nabla f(y)),$$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. Note that $$ g'(t) =  (\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y))^{T} \nabla^2 f (y+t(x-y)) (x-y), $$ for all $t \in (0,1).$  Consequently, by the mean value theorem, there is a $\bar{t} \in (0,1)$ such that
$$\begin{align}
\| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\|^2 = {} & g(1)-g(0)\\
   = {}& g'(\bar{t}) \\
= {} & (\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y))^{T}\nabla^2 f(y+\bar{t} (x-y)) (x-y) \\
\leq {} & \| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \| \|\nabla^2 f (y+\bar{t}(x-y))\| \|x-y\| 
\end{align}$$ Hence, $$\| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\| \leq \|\nabla^2 f (y+\bar{t}(x-y))\| \|x-y\|.$$ Since $\|\nabla^2 f (y+\bar{t}(x-y))\|\leq M,$ we have $$\| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\| \leq M \|x-y\|.$$

If you want to change the norm, you can use the fact all norms are equivalent.